# Android getText Issue

Tags: android, offset, gettext

This is the code I used

```
    int offset = getArguments().getInt("offset");
    currentoffset.setText(Integer.toString(offset));
    Log.d("Currentoffset",currentoffset.getText().toString());
    Log.d("Offset",Integer.toString(offset));
```

but when I run it there is a different output from textview and Logs.
This is the output:

```
field                     values
TextView                  1  2  0
Log.d(currentoffset)      2  3 -1
Log.d(offset)             2  3 -1
```

> QUESTION:Why is there a difference between them? And how should I solve it?

If there is something you need to know please ask.
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? It looks like you are answering all your questions...

Comment: @DroidChris textview value is correct and i want to use this value somewhere else . but the value is not the same there !!!

Comment: getText works correctly-  notice currentoffset and offset match.  If you have a problem with what's on screen, its being overwritten elsewhere.

Comment: have you tried - currentoffset.setText(String.valueOf(int offset));  to see if the output is any different?

Comment: Where else would you like to use this value? Please explain more.

Comment: @DroidChris this is part of Persian calendar. And this part is from fragment called Monthfragment . I want to use it to calculate month name in MainActivity . I used open source code provide at github [https://github.com/ebraminio/DroidPersianCalendar](https://github.com/ebraminio/DroidPersianCalendar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can suppose with your code is that you are running the code multiple times, and calling getArguments() without setting the new argument given.